# Need help fixing the normals for my stylized foliage

Tags: texturing, eevee-render-engine, normal-map

Im working hard on getting **stylized/cartoonish** looking grass or generally **foliage** in evee.

My goal is not to creating realisitic stuff, instead such as from games like the *witness* or *rime*.

[image]

They have this great **fluffy looking foliage**. I searched alot but it was impossible to find a solution which fits my conditions.

• **Textured planes (Low poly)**

• **ressource friendly**

• **Good looking shadows, without baking if possible (Grass shouldnt creat shadows but should recieve from other sources)**

• **Foliage should look fluffy so that u see the meshes as a single bunch**

• **Set up and rendering in Evee.**

• **No scripting**

Im actually struggeling with the normals on my planes. If u can see in the following picture Im having trouble with the normals. If I combine multiple meshes or use them in a particle system, the direction of the normals make the grass looking weired if they are rotated. Im pretty newbie in texturing/shading so pls consider a little bit instruction. My conditions doesnt have highest priority but pls try to stick to it.

[image]

**Edit**: I found this Image which shows the technique I am looking for but 
I dont know how to achieve this method in blender. It has something to do with bending the vertex normals in a specific direction.

[image]

**Im thankful for every help!**

If u have any questions or need something, pls tell me!

Comment: Your issue is no the normal map (but do try out if you actually need it), but with the lighting. Lower the strength, turn the camera, alter the lighting. That should give you a decent feel of how the scene behaves.

Comment: Nah that has nothing to do with the position/strengt of the light or camera. Ur method could work in a static picture but my goal is to animate a scene. So I could rotate the camera or the grass in the right position, but thats not the efficient way. But thanks for ur hint!

Comment: I just checked your material setup. Is there a reason why you use a principled shader with all values set to 0? Try a different shader and/or use an emission map, it might help concealing the issue.

Comment: That could be a solution. But thats why I mentioned that Im not the super experienced blender guy, I need a instruction. I already played around the emission shader but because emission is casting light, it cant recieve shadows.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but if you use the emission component (with a texture) of the principled shader there should be some shadow left. It will also weaken/cancel out your normals btw. I didn't have the time to try it out, but my guess is: leaving out the normal map could solve your problem, maybe a little emission influence for tweaking.

Comment: also - it just came to me - there is a Geometry -> backfacing input. You could try inverting the normal map if it's backfacing.

Comment: Im really thankful for ur endeavor... but thats totally not what I am looking for.

Comment: Can you give us a link to the page that image came from, and which of the results would suit you best?